# How do you check if MongoDB is still indexing?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Just inserted some data, and used a script to tell MongoDB to index the data, but is there a Mongo shell command where I can check wether the indexing is complete?

Comment: Here's a nice scripted solution: http://werxltd.com/wp/2011/08/21/mongodb-script-to-check-the-status-of-background-index-builds/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `db.currentOp()` in the shell to see if your indexing operation is still in progress.

See more info in the documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes/#monitor-and-control-index-building).

Comment: How is that useful, I got 800 lines of output in JSON format?

Comment: Isn't there a subcommand for it that says to show only operations related to an index that the person changed or added? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309268/mongodb-status-of-index-creation-job