# mongodb status of index creation job

Tags: mongodb, background, indexing, jobs

I'm using MongoDB and have a collection with roughly 75 million records.
I have added a compound index on two "fields" by using the following command:

```
db.my_collection.ensureIndex({"data.items.text":1, "created_at":1},{background:true}).
```

Two days later I'm trying to see the status of the index creation. Running `db.currentOp()` returns `{}`, however when I try to create another index I get this error message:

```
cannot add index with a background operation in progress.
```

Is there a way to check the status/progress of the index creation job?

One thing to add - I am using mongodb version 2.0.6. Thanks!

Comment: What does db.my_collection.getIndexes() show you?  Is the index already created?

Comment: This is also a good link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-in-progress-indexing-operations/

Comment: Anand - getIndexes() lists the new index. However, I'm not sure that it means that the job completed.

Comment: By what I've just experienced and read in here if an Index appears under the Collection it still doesn't mean the job is completed. Am I correct?

Answer (score 76):

At the mongo shell, type below command to see the current progress:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(op){ if(op.msg!==undefined) print(op.msg) })

Index Build (background) Index Build (background): 1431577/55212209 2%
```

To do a real-time running status log:

```
> while (true) { db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(op){ if(op.msg!==undefined) print(op.msg) }); sleep(1000); }
Index Build: scanning collection Index Build: scanning collection: 43687948/47760207 91%
Index Build: scanning collection Index Build: scanning collection: 43861991/47760228 91%
Index Build: scanning collection Index Build: scanning collection: 44993874/47760246 94%
Index Build: scanning collection Index Build: scanning collection: 45968152/47760259 96%
```

Comment: I typed this in my mongo shell but nothing comes out. And if I just typed db.currentOp() it will output "inprog" : [ { "host" : "ip-172-31-18-127:27017", "desc" : "conn28", "connectionId" : 28, "client" : "127.0.0.1:34690", "appName" : "MongoDB Shell", "clientMetadata" : { "application" : { "name" : "MongoDB Shell" },

Comment: For sharded cluster:
    db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(op){ if(op.msg!==undefined) print(op.shard, op.msg) })

Comment: I just see "Index Build: draining writes received during build" - any ideas?

Comment: This also works with Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB

Answer (score 16):

You could use *currentOp* with a **true** argument which returns a more verbose output, including idle connections and system operations.

```
db.currentOp(true)
```

... and then you could use *db.killOp()* to Kill the desired operation.

Comment: Thank you Cesar - running db.currentOp(true) returns the same {}. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions.
After a lot more searching I found [this post](http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/02/mongodb-currentop-killop/)! that clarifies that in an auth-enabled environment db.currentOp() works only for admin users, which are users that auth into the admin db.
Once I used that user I saw real output from the command.

Answer (score 14):

The following should print out index progress:

```
db
  .currentOp({"command.createIndexes": { $exists : true } })
  .inprog
  .forEach(function(op){ print(op.msg) })
```

outputs:

```
Index Build (background) Index Build (background): 5311727/27231147 19%
```

Comment: That didn't work for me (prints nothing), so I modified it to `db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(op){ print(op.msg) })` and now it prints additional rows of `[unknown type]` stuff but at least it prints the index build % as well, which is a lot cleaner than CesarTrigo's `db.currentOp(true)` that print's a lot more stuff

Comment: Use this instead:
`db.currentOp({
    "query.createIndexes": { $exists : true } }).inprog.forEach(function(op){ 
    print(op.msg) 
})`

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, [DR9885](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49059430/2284676) answer didn't work for me, it has spaces in the code (syntax error) and even if the spaces are removed, it returns nothing.

This works as of Mongo Shell `v3.6.0`

```
db.currentOp().inprog.forEach(function(op){ if(op.msg) print(op.msg) })
```

Didn't read [Bajal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50138275/2284676) answer until after I posted mine, but it's almost exactly the same except that it's slightly shorter code and also works.

Comment: I typed this in my mongo shell but nothing comes out. And if I just typed `db.currentOp()` it will output `"inprog" : [
                {
                        "host" : "ip-172-31-18-127:27017",
                        "desc" : "conn28",
                        "connectionId" : 28,
                        "client" : "127.0.0.1:34690",
                        "appName" : "MongoDB Shell",
                        "clientMetadata" : {
                                "application" : {
                                        "name" : "MongoDB Shell"
                                },`

Answer (score 7):

I like:

```
db.currentOp({ 
    'msg' :{ $exists: true },
    'command': { $exists: true },
    $or: [ 
        { 'command.createIndexes': { $exists: true } }, 
        { 'command.reIndex': { $exists: true } }
    ]
}).inprog.forEach(function(op) { 
    print(op.msg); 
});
```

Output example:

> Index Build Index Build: 84826/335739 25%

Documentation suggests:

```
db.adminCommand(
    {
      currentOp: true,
      $or: [
        { op: "command", "command.createIndexes": { $exists: true }  },
        { op: "none", "msg" : /^Index Build/ }
      ]
    }
)
```

[Active Indexing Operations example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#examples).

Comment: The question stated: Running db.currentOp() returns {}.  So would this answer not also return {}?

Answer (score 3):

Simple one to just check progress of a single index going on:

```
db.currentOp({"msg":/Index/}).inprog[0].progress;
```

outputs:

```
{ "done" : 86007212, "total" : 96868386 }
```

Comment: I just get uncaught exception: TypeError: db.currentOp(...).inprog[0] is undefined :

Answer (score 2):

Find progress of index jobs, nice one liner:

```
> db.currentOp().inprog.map(a => a.msg)
[
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    "Index Build: scanning collection Index Build: scanning collection: 16448156/54469342 30%",
    undefined,
    undefined
]
```